# Android Studio Bumblebee constantly freezes on Mac Apple M1 chip

Tags: android, android-studio, apple-m1

First of all, it is **NOT** below issue:

```
Fixed in Android Studio 4.2
IDE freezes on macOS Big Sur: Android Studio 4.1 might freeze when you open a dialog.
```

I'm using a version higher than 4.2 and even if I change the system settings about "Prefer Tabs" to "never", the freeze issue still exists.

The IDE freezes like more than 5 times a day, mostly happens **when it is building**, and the project is using Jetpack Compose, have to CMD+OPTION+ESC to kill the process and restart.

More info about the environment:

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111, built on February 2, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart (211.7798), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40), io.flutter (64.0.2), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)
```

**Android Studio Preview** has this freeze issue too.

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Beta 2
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8125332, built on January 28, 2022
```

Comment: Same happening here in my Mac with intel chip. This was not happening in Artic Fox version. A workmate suffers the same issue on windows.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. macOS 12.3 with Intel as well as M1 MacBooks.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like latest Preview version is working fine, at least it doesn't freeze.

[Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Canary 3](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)

**Update on 13/Apr/2022:**

Just tried  [Android Studio Dolphin (2021.3.1) Canary 8](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)

It has new features regarding logcat but still freezes when debugging, so I do NOT recommend upgrading to that version.

Comment: For me it keeps freezing on Mac with Intel chip.